# Why doesn't += work in recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I noticed if I use `+=` in recursion it runs indefinitely because the variable being used in the termination statement doesn't increase in value. I can't figure out why, I've already looked on the forum for an answer but didn't see one. I'm trying to figure out if I'm doing something  wrong and if not I'm looking for an answer on the specifics as to why it's not working.

```
//this works fine
function recure(n = 0) {
    if (n > 10) {
        console.log('The End');
        return '';
    }
    console.log(n);
    setTimeout(function () {
        recure(n + 1)
    }, 1000);
}
recure();

//this also works fine, note it's working with n+=1
function loop(amount = 10, n = 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        console.log(n);
        n += 1;
    }
}

//This doesn't work and is the reason for the post, why?
function recure(n = 0) {
    if (n > 10) {
        console.log('The End');
        return '';  
    }
    console.log(n);
    n += 1;
    setTimeout(function () {
        recure()
    }, 1000);
}
recure();    //it indefinitely logs 0
```

Comment: Each call initializes a local `n` with a value of `0`. Pass `n` to the recursive call. `recurse(n)`

Comment: `recure(n=0)`....

Comment: You don't pass the updated value of `n` so it's defaulting to 0?

Comment: change setTimeout to `setTimeout(function(){recure(n)},1000);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n` is local to the particular call of a function. Since you call your function without arguments it will bind the **new** `n` gets bound to `0`.

```
function test(n=0){
  return n;
}

test();  //==> 0
test(2); //==> 2
```

Recursion isn't really treated special so if you assume that `n` is kept between calls to `recure` this should also happen:

```
function other(n=0) {
  return n;
}
function test(n=0) {
  n++;
  return other();
}

test(0); // ==> 1
```

However this is absurd since `n` is local and thus every call have it's won `n` even if the function is the same.

Also note that the third example is not recursion since the call stack gets reset.

The anonymous function where you call `recure` has `n` in it's lexical scope so you can just call it with `n+1` so the new `recure` will get a `n` that is one higher than the call the thunk derived from.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript scope of variables is defined by functions. So, when you are calling the function recure() a new scope is getting created with new "N" in each scope.

Let's try to understand what you are doing here:

```
1. You called recure(). 
 // No argument hence "N" is undefined therefore N is assigned 0.

2. You incremented value of "N"
 // New value of "N" = 1

3. You recursively called recure()
 // Again no argument hence "N" is 0
 // Since, recure() is called again new scope is created
 // This "N" is different from the "N" used is step 1

4. Bad recursion --> #Fail.
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//this works fine
function recure(n = 0){
    if (n > 10) {
        console.log('The End');
        return '';
    }
    console.log(n);
    setTimeout(function() {
        recure(n + 1)
    }, 1000);
}
recure();

//this also works fine, note it's working with n+=1
function loop(amount = 10, n = 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        console.log(n);
        n += 1;
    }
}

//This doesn't work and is the reason for the post, why?
function recure(n = 0) {
    if (n > 10) {
        console.log('The End');
        return '';  
    }
    console.log(n);
    n += 1;
  setTimeout(function(){recure(n)},1000);
}
recure();    //it indefinitely logs 0
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
function recure(n=0){
    if(n>10){
        console.log("The End");
        return "";  
      }
    console.log(n);
    n+=1;
    setTimeout(function(){recure(n)},1000);
  }
recure();
```

At every stage of recursion, that particular closure should know the previous recursion state. 
We are passing 'n' to know the state of recursion.